# EF Core querying gives an error "Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql. The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET 6 and PostgreSQL database.

I have a `hosted service`, which periodically calls `repository's function` and is `querying database entities` using `EF Core` as so:

```
public class NotificationRepository : INotificationRepository
    {
        public async Task<List<Notification>> GetUnreadDeviceNotifications()
        {
            using var context = new MyDbContext();
            return await context.Notifications.Where(x => !x.IsSentTimestamp.HasValue && x.ChannelId == 8).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

As soon as I deploy on `linux` machine and every time service calls `GetUnreadDeviceNotifications` I get this error:

```
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=6.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]: File name: 'Npgsql, Version=6.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension.ExtensionInfo.GetServiceProviderHashCode()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions.GetHashCode()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at my-app.Infrastructure.Repositories.NotificationRepository.GetUnreadDeviceNotifications() in C:\Projects\my-app\src\my-app.Infrastructure\Repositories\NotificationRepository.cs:line 22
Aug 07 12:50:46 my-app my-app.Web[1432629]:    at my-app.Application.Services.MessagingServices.NotificationReadingService.DoWork(Object state) in C:\Projects\my-app\src\my-app.Application\Services\MessagingServices\NotificationReadingService.cs:line 35
```

These are `dependencies` I have:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="10.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

P.S. It seems that it is working fine on `Windows`

Comment: You have referenced version 6.0.3 but it's looking for 6.0.8, and not finding it.

Comment: I kinda understand that, but why is it looking for 6.0.8 then? I have tried updating it to 6.0.8 but it got even worse

Comment: You can try removing the references and add them again. Also try text search to find out where it's picking. Hope you are using nuget package manager for adding references.

Comment: That's what I already did.. I've searched for '6.0.8' and found nothing. I also re-installed most of the packages.

Comment: Also, if I update my Npgsql package to 6.0.9 it gives the same error, but with 6.0.9 version

Comment: "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" package is dependent on "Npgsql". So might be the EF version used is newer than the npgsql. One thing you may try is that update both these packages to latest/compatible version and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have a project with the following configuration:

[Project Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlKzl.png)

[Program.cs or StartUp.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60hoy.png)

[My Hosted Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KvJp.png)

I can connect to the database and get query results.

Remember to declare in your Startup.cs or Program.cs your repository services.
Another one important thing to note, is that you cannot access to the repository instance from the Hosted Service, because it's a Singleton, so the best approach to reach your repository is to use an IServiceProvider instance.
My English speaking is not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to .NET 7 resolved all the problems.